# Is it possible to get the details of the node where the pod ran before restart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm running a kubernetes cluster of 20+ nodes. And one pod in a namespace got restarted. The pod got killed due to OOM with exit code 137 and restarted again as expected. But would like to know the node in which the pod was running earlier. Any place we could check the logs for the info? Like tiller, kubelet, kubeproxy etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But would like to know the node in which the pod was running earlier.

If a pod is killed with `ExitCode: 137`, e.g. when it used more memory than its limit, it will be restarted on the same node - not re-scheduled. For this, check your metrics or container logs.

But Pods can also be killed due to over-committing a node, see e.g. [How to troubleshoot Kubernetes OOM and CPU Throttle](https://sysdig.com/blog/troubleshoot-kubernetes-oom/).

Comment: Thanks Jonas. In my case, I see only 2 nodes has already hit the resource limit w.r.t memory. i.e) the limit applied on the node is more than what is allocated. Also the node where the pod ran/running still has limit within the node capacity. if it's killed, then I suppose that the pod is re-scheduled onto a different node? Exit Code 137 means  the system terminated the container. Here the system means the actual node or any other kube-component?

Comment: Exit Code 137 means that the container is killed by a Linux process, https://medium.com/tailwinds-navigator/kubernetes-tip-how-does-oomkilled-work-ba71b135993b

Comment: Ok. In my case it is restarted on the same node since it is OOM. Thanks Jonas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `Promql` query where it fetches `nodename`, `pod name`, `namespace` from which pod got restarted:

```
sum(kube_pod_info * on(pod, namespace) group_left(node) 
sum(changes(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[5m])) by (namespace, pod) > 0) by (node, pod, namespace)
```